# Enums Returning Arrays Stream

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to validate a field against some predefined values (that can grow in future). So for this I have created a Enum and defined a method that returns the stream of the allowed values.

```
public enum EnumDemo {

    VERSION("1.0.0","2.0.3");

    private List<String> ver;

    EnumDemo(String... ver) {
        this.ver = Arrays.asList(ver);
    }

    public List<String> getVer() {
        return ver;
    }

    public static Stream<EnumDemo> stream() {
        return Arrays.stream(EnumDemo.values());
    }
}
```

Now I need to validate a field against the values defined in this Enum.

I'm using:

```
Optional<EnumDemo> ab = EnumDemo.stream()
.map(l -> {l.getVer().stream()
                     .filter(c -> c.equals("2.0.3"))
                     .findFirst();})
.findFirst();

System.out.println(ab.get().getVer());
```

But it is giving me compilation error. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Compilation Error:

```
The method map(Function<? super EnumDemo,? extends R>) in the type Stream<EnumDemo> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> l) -> {})
```

Comment: can you provide us the error message?

Comment: Remove the `{;}`, or add a `return` after `{`.

Comment: It would help if you would show the actual error over just saying "there is an error".

Comment: @Jai -- Didn't work :(

Comment: sorry for not pasting the comppilation error

Comment: If you want to find the first enum value with that string, I would use `stream().filter(e -> e.getVer().contains("...")).findFirst()`.

Comment: @Abhishek it doesn't work because your first `findFirst` should be `anyMatch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write it this way:

```
Optional<EnumDemo> ab = EnumDemo.stream().filter(l -> l.getVer().contains("2.0.3"))
                                         .findFirst();
```

By the way, it wasn't working because you used `{}` for the lambda expression, so it was expecting a `return` statement in the `{}`. You could either remove the `{}` (along with the `;`) or add in the `return`.

Anyway the original codes looked confusing, not sure if I guessed the intention correctly, but this implementation should be clearer.

#### Edit

Based on your comment, this is what you need:

```
EnumDemo.stream().flatMap(l -> l.getVer().stream())
                 .filter("2.0.3"::equals)
                 .findAny()
                 .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

#### Update

Holger commented that there is a shorter and more meaningful way, with better performance:

```
if(EnumDemo.stream()
           .anyMatch(l -> l.getVer().contains(userString))) {
    System.out.println(userString);
}
```

Comment: I already tried this. But it returns the complete list to Optional. I need only the element which matched the user input. System.out.println(ab.get().getVer()); prints  [1.0.0, 2.0.3]

Comment: @Abhishek That is the enum which matched, but this enum (`EnumDemo.VERSION`) does indeed have more than 1 version values, which is correct.

Comment: @Abhishek Obviously people are **misunderstanding** you now, perhaps you could add a demo/case to clarify your thought. b.t.w I don't think it's a good choice using stream here.

Comment: Basically my intention is to validate a field against the allowed values and if it validates, I want to print the allowed value from my code, not print the field.

Comment: Second snippet doesn't compile, remove: `Optional<EnumDemo> ab = ` or use `.peek` instead of `.ifPresent`

Comment: Jai, it worked for me, Just one concern, what if I want to assign that 2.0.3 to a variable?

Comment: @Abhishek You simply move it to a variable and replace that constant string with the variable.

Comment: I did it with Optional<String> ab = EnumDemo.stream().flatMap(l -> l.getVer().stream())
        .filter("2.0.3"::equals)
        .findAny();

Comment: There is no sense in searching for the string that matches the user input, as the user input itself is already the string that matches the user input. The only relevant result information is whether that string is valid, i.e. a `boolean`. So you can simply use `if(EnumDemo.stream().anyMatch(l -> l.getVer().contains(userString))) System.out.println(userString);` instead of that `flatMap` thing.

Answer (score 3):

To understand it, you have to think about lambdas. Lambdas represent `interface`s but are specially treated by the JVM, so not every Lambda needs a class to represent. (Stateless lambdas can be just methods).

Now when looking at the `map()` method in the `Stream` interface:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
```

You see that it expects an implementation of the `Function` interface. You now have many different ways to provide that mapper. In this example lets map from `Object` to `String`:

## 1. Using an inline lambda:

```
.map(o -> o.toString())
```

## 2. Using a multiline lambda:

```
.map(o -> { 
    return o.toString(); 
})
```

## 3. Using method references:

```
.map(Object::toString)
```

## 4. Using an anonymous class:

```
.map(new Function<Object, String>(){
     @Override
     public String apply(Object o){
         return o.toString();
     }
})
```

Your current code uses the **2.** approach. But without a `return` statement. This is even better seen when looking at the anonymous class at **4.**. It seems natural, that when not using a `return` statement in a method that no value is returned.

> And that's why you get the compilation error.

You just have to add the `return` statement:

```
.map(l -> {
    return l.getVer().stream()
        .filter(c -> c.equals("2.0.3"))
        .findFirst();
});
```

---

Or remove the brackets `{}`:

```
.map(l -> l.getVer().stream()
    .filter(c -> c.equals("2.0.3"))
    .findFirst());
```

---

Or even use the approach provided by @Jai in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51416115/5515060). Which works even better, than what you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `lambda` expression and not returning any value so it is giving compilation error. It is better to use `ifPresent()`

```
String val="2.0.3";
EnumDemo.stream()
    .flatMap(l -> l.getVer().stream())
    .filter(c -> c.equals(val))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(x -> System.out.println(x));
```